# Inaccessible partition

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partition-recovery

I am using desktop running Windows XP.

My PC has an 80GB hard disk with 4 partitions: C, D, E & F

Partitions C,D & F open easily but when I double click on "E" drive in my computer then it immediately disappears and screen goes off for few seconds then comes back on.
So, I'm unable to see and read the contents of that "E" drive.

Comment: What exactly is "normal mode"?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like some sort of corruption.

First try accessing it from **cmd**:

```
dir e:\
```

If this doesn't do anything meaningful, check for error messages during boot-up.

If booting is error-free, right-click on My Computer, then select **Manage** and in the box that comes up **Disk Management**.

If the **E:** partition shows as healthy, right-click on it, select **Properties** and in the **Tools** tab select **Check Now...**.

Don't allow corrections in the first instance, unless you can recreate the drive, but just see how bad the problem is. If it is very bad, then trying to correct will only make it worse.

If there are a lot of errors, then you will need to use advanced tools to recover it, but you may find it easier to recreate from back-ups.